# Prove by definition $p$ is differentiable in all point $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $d_p(a,b)=bx+ay$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $p(x,y)=xy$. Prove by definition $p$ is differentiable in all point $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $d_p(a,b)=bx+ay$

My work:

Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, We need to show $p$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$.

> $lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{p((a,b)+(t,0))-p(a,b)}{t}=lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{p((a+t,b))-p(a,b)}{t}=lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{(a+t)b-ab}{t}=b$

For other way, we have:

> $lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{p((a,b)+(0,t))-p(a,b)}{t}=lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{p((a,b+t))-p(a,b)}{t}=lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{a(b+t)-ab}{t}=a$

As $(a,b)$ is arbitrary, then $p$ is differentiable in all point $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

My question:

1) Is this by definition?, Because i think i need to solve this exercise proving this:
$lim_{\hat{h}\rightarrow\hat{0}\frac{||p(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-p(\bar h)-dp\bar{x}(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}=0}$

2) How can i prove $d_p(a,b)=bx+ay$?

Thanks for all.

Comment: Those definitions are not for differentiability, they are definitions of partial derivatives

Comment: @daulomb Then i need to make the limit $lim_{\hat{h}\rightarrow\hat{0}\frac{||p(\bar{x}+\bar{h})-p(\bar h)-dp\bar{x}(\bar{h})||}{||\bar{h}||}=0}$ no?

Comment: I  saw some mistake and corrected

Comment: By the way $d_p$ is $bdx+ady$ not $bx+ay$.

Comment: I would write $d_{(x,y)} (a,b) = bx+ay$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|(x_1+h_1)(x_2+h_2) - x_1 x_2 - (x_2 h_1 +x_1 h_2)| =|h_1h_2|\le \|h\|^2 $.

In particular, if $f(x) = x_1 x_2$ then the above shows that
$Df(x)h = x_2 h_1 +x_1 h_2$.

**Note**: In the notation of the question (see 1)) this becomes
${|p(x+h) - p(x) - dp_x(h)| \over \|h\|} \le \|h\| $, where
$dp_x(h) = x_2 h_1 +x_1 h_2$.

Comment: Excellent. Thats is very clear. I try to prove the limit, but, how do you find this term"$-(x_2h_1+x_1h_2)$? is the only thing i don't have in my proof. Can you explain me that part?

Comment: @Bvss12: You just show partial differentiability. The above shows that $p$ is differentiable with derivative $dp_x$. I rewrote the equation using the notation in the question.

Answer (score 1):

$p_x(a, b)=\displaystyle \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{p(a+t,b)-p(a,b)}{t}=\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{(a+t)b-ab}{t}=b\,$ (Partial derivative of $p$ w.r. to $x$ at $(a,b)$.

$p_y(a, b)=\displaystyle \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{p(a,t+b)-p(a,b)}{t}=\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{(b+t)a-ab}{t}=a.$ (Partial derivative of $p$ w.r. to $y$ at $(a,b)$.

For differentiability look at this limit:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{(h, k)\rightarrow (0 0)}\frac{p(a+h,b+k)-p(a,b)-p_x(a,b)-p_y(a,b)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0.\,(\text{you can check this it will be ok)}$$

Since $p$ is differentiable, it is total differntial at $(a,b)$ is $dp(a,b)=p_x(a,b)dx+p_y(a,b)dy=bdx+ady.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is clear.

Comment: you're welcome regards